# How to convert numbers into category in a column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion

How to convert integers to categories "Less than or equal to 20" and "Greater than 20" in column name 'A'?

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Thousands thanks!

Comment: pd.cut(df['A'],bins=[0,20.0,df['A'].max()],labels=['less then 20','larger 20 '])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
In [744]: df
Out[744]: 
    A
0  12
1  23
2  18
3  39
4  15

In [744]: import numpy as np
In [745]: conditions = [df.A.le(20), df.A.gt(20)]

In [746]: choices = ['Less than or equal to 20', 'Greater than 20']

In [749]: df['categorical_A'] = np.select(conditions, choices)

In [750]: df
Out[750]: 
    A             categorical_A
0  12  Less than or equal to 20
1  23           Greater than 20
2  18  Less than or equal to 20
3  39           Greater than 20
4  15  Less than or equal to 20
```

Comment: You're a genius! Bro!